# Problem with account data serialization and deserializatin

Tags: solana-program, pda, deserialization, borsh, state

I'm working on a Solana program and encountered an issue related to state management with Program Derived Accounts (PDAs).

I successfully created a state for my Solana program and saved it to a PDA (Program Derived Account). However, when I attempt to retrieve the state from the PDA, I encounter the following error:     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown

here is instruction code:

```
use borsh::{BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{AccountInfo, next_account_info},
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    sysvar::{rent::Rent, Sysvar},
};
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use crate::state::{State, Distribution};
use solana_program::msg;


#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct InitializeArgs {
    pub initial_ticket_prices: Vec<u64>,
    pub initial_token_addresses: Vec<Pubkey>,
    pub min_buy_amounts: Vec<u64>,
    pub distributions: Vec<Distribution>,
    pub max_tickets_per_user: u64,
    pub total_tickets_threshold: u64,
    pub depth: u64,
    pub rewards_percent_by_depth: Vec<u64>,
    pub ref_code_length: u64
}

pub fn initialize(program_id: &Pubkey, accounts: &[AccountInfo], args: InitializeArgs) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let state_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    
    let mut state = State::try_from_slice(&state_account.data.borrow()).unwrap_or_else(|_| State {
        ticket_prices: BTreeMap::new(),
        min_buy_amounts: BTreeMap::new(),
        deposited_by_token: BTreeMap::new(),
        address_to_ref_code: BTreeMap::new(),
        ref_code_to_address: BTreeMap::new(),
        referrer_to_referrals: BTreeMap::new(),
        referral_to_referrer: BTreeMap::new(),
        user_tickets: BTreeMap::new(),
        user_rewards: BTreeMap::new(),
        rewards_percent_by_depth: BTreeMap::new(),
        distributions: Vec::new(),
        max_tickets_per_user: 0,
        total_tickets_threshold: 0,
        ref_code_length: 0,
        total_tickets: 0,
        depth: 0,
        paused: false,
    });
    
    let token_addresses_clone = args.initial_token_addresses.clone();

    args.initial_token_addresses.into_iter().zip(args.initial_ticket_prices).for_each(|(token_address, price)| {
        state.ticket_prices.insert(token_address, price);
    });

    token_addresses_clone.into_iter().zip(args.min_buy_amounts).for_each(|(token_address, amount)| {
        state.min_buy_amounts.insert(token_address, amount);
    });

    state.distributions = args.distributions;
    state.max_tickets_per_user = args.max_tickets_per_user;
    state.total_tickets_threshold = args.total_tickets_threshold;
    state.depth = args.depth;
    state.ref_code_length = args.ref_code_length;
    
    args.rewards_percent_by_depth.into_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(index, percent)| {
        state.rewards_percent_by_depth.insert(index as u64 + 1, percent);
    });

    state.serialize(&mut *state_account.data.borrow_mut())?;
    
    let state = State::try_from_slice(&state_account.data.borrow())?;
        
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This all looks correct. Maybe you need to wait until the transaction with `initialize` is confirmed before sending your next transaction, or perhaps the next transaction is using an incorrect pubkey.